# _Layout programming lost after Nuget Update-Package with Visual Studio 17

Tags: layout, nuget

After applying Update-Package on a long solid MVC Application, the _Layout markup has been lost. This took place in 4/26/2017.
I couldn't determine which updated component from NuGet is causing the error.
However, I also created a new clean .NET Framework MVC Application. With no other actions, did an Update-Package. The new Application has also lost its _Layout rendering. My framework level is 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the problems is the result of the Nuget batch Update-Package modifying the Bootstrap version to 4.1.0
The fix is using Nuget Package Manager on References and lowering the Bootstrap version to 3.3.7 At least my new clean trial MVC application is then correctly displaying the _ Layout page.
But this hasn't corrected my major application.

Further Fix. In my main application I removed using Nuget in the following order:

- Bootstrap
- Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation
- jQuery.Validation
- jQuery

Then clear the Scripts folder in the Project View
In the reverse order of above Install, at the latest version:

jQuery

jQuery.Validation

Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation

Bootstrap(**3.3.7**)

Now the Scripts Folder should be regenerated.
At this point my application is displaying the correct _Layout